# Why do I get bad file descriptor while running rerun Go package in iTerm2?

Tags: go, iterm2

Im using a [rerun Go package](https://github.com/ivpusic/rerun) in a iTerm2 terminal and getting an error

> Error while reading list of files to listen! bad file descriptor

This error comes from filepath.Walk function. The thing is that everything works fine in integrated VSCode terminal but not in iTerm2. I could guarantee that config file is 100% correct (rerun says that config is incorrect in other way plus we use this config for couple years in a team). Also I would like to mention that iTerm2 has a Full Disk Access in the MacOS privacy settings.

Would be so thankful for any info or help regarding my problem.

Im on macOS Monterey 12.1, M1 Max.

Full error:

```
rerun -c rerun.json
git/ivp/rer 21:40:28 ☹[PANI] ▶ Error while reading list of files to listen! bad file descriptor
panic: Error while reading list of files to listen! %s

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/ivpusic/golog.(*Logger).Panicf(0xc000166100, {0x12024a8, 0x2f}, {0xc00015de98, 0x1e51ff8, 0x18})
    /Users/greenwookez/go/pkg/mod/github.com/ivpusic/golog@v0.0.0-20170608213328-28640bee649f/logger.go:315 +0x134
main.(*watcher).start(0xc0001261e0)
    /Users/greenwookez/go/pkg/mod/github.com/ivpusic/rerun@v0.0.0-20170331080801-adc8acf1481b/watcher.go:147 +0x2ef
main.main()
    /Users/greenwookez/go/pkg/mod/github.com/ivpusic/rerun@v0.0.0-20170331080801-adc8acf1481b/main.go:51 +0x2af
```

Comment: Add verbose `-v` flag and rerun. Maybe it will write more info.

Comment: What's your working directory when you run the command? https://github.com/ivpusic/rerun/blob/adc8acf1481b4ec9011e964dd85c68f12609201c/watcher.go#L126-L148

Comment: @serge-v Unfortunately, it doesn't. The output is the same.

Comment: @Zyl my working directory is smth like root/src/server. It does contain config file for sure. I'am able to run this command via VSCode integrated terminal but I'am not able to do that via iTerm2. (＞﹏＜)

Comment: How do you start VsCode? Can VsCode still do it if you launch it with command `code` from iTerm2?

Comment: @Zyl Rerun works in VSCode when it is launched from terminal context and via MacOS UI both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue was reproduced via default Mac OS terminal so I decided to reinstall Mac OS from scratch (instead of migrating from the old Mac with bunch of different configs) and add an `unlim -n <more than 256>` to the `.zprofile`. Hopefully it will help someone.